# How many states can be restricted in that way - Azure DevOps work items?

Tags: azure-devops

Using the rule `A work item state moved from [State A]` Then `Restrict the state transition to [State B]`
How many such states can be included in the `Restrict the state transition to` action

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops#rule-definitions